# How to get list of bus stations in between the source and destination with GOOGLE MAPS IN iOS Swift

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift2, google-places-api

Hello every one I am working with Google maps, I have a requirement to show list of bus stops in between the source and destination within the city. I tried my best but I am not able to get the result. Please help me on this.

Hi all i am using below api but not getting list of bus stations between the source and destination 
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Raidurg‌​am Bus Stop, Old Mumbai Highway, Madhura Nagar Colony, Gachibowli, Hyderabad, Telangana 500032&destination=Mehdipatnam Bus Stop, Mehdipatnam Road, Santosh Nagar, Mehdipatnam, Hyderabad, Telangana 500028&mode=transit&types=bus_station&key= API_KEY"

THANKS IN ADVANCE

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

        let path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: rout)
        let polilin = GMSPolyline(path: path)
        polilin.strokeWidth = 4.0
        polilin.map = self.mapView
        polilin.tappable = true
        var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
        for index in 1...path!.count() {
            bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(path!.coordinateAtIndex(index))
        }
        self.mapView.animateWithCameraUpdate(GMSCameraUpdate.fitBounds(bounds))
        self.mapView.trafficEnabled = true

    })
```

Comment: you have to use google place api for that

Comment: yes i am using google places api only, But I couldnt get any bus stations list between the points

Comment: Hi all i am using below api but not getting list of bus stations between the source and destination "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Raidurgam Bus Stop, Old Mumbai Highway, Madhura Nagar Colony, Gachibowli, Hyderabad, Telangana 500032&destination=Mehdipatnam Bus Stop, Mehdipatnam Road, Santosh Nagar, Mehdipatnam, Hyderabad, Telangana 500028&mode=transit&types=bus_station&key= API_KEY"

Comment: please help me on this

Comment: @BoosaRamesh , did you find any solution to this problem. Can you please share I also have same kind of requirement to work on. thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=API_KEY&location=source_lat_long&radius=500&types=bus_station

parameters

radius-->Distance_Between_Source_Destination in meter.

location-->Source_lat_long.

Comment: Thanks Mahipal, THis api will help us to get nearby busstaion  only, But i want all the bus stations between the points, for example if we want to travel from one place to another by bus, i need the bus stations list between the points